# Copy multiple workbooks into a single workbooks with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy multiple excel workbooks to a single excel workbook with the below, but it is only copying 6 columns when I have 35.

```
#Get a list of files to copy from
   $Files = GCI 'C:\Users\bob\Desktop\Und' | ?{$_.Extension -Match "xlsx?"} |    select -ExpandProperty FullName

  #Launch Excel, and make it do as its told (supress confirmations)
  $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
  $Excel.Visible = $True
  $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False

  #Open up a new workbook
  $Dest = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()


 `enter code here` ForEach($File in $Files[0..4]){
    $Source = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File,$true,$true)
    If(($Dest.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Count -eq 1) -and ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty  ($Dest.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value2))){ #If there is only 1 used cell and it is blank select A1
        [void]$source.ActiveSheet.Range("A1","F$(($Source.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows|Select -Last 1).Row)").Copy()
        [void]$Dest.Activate()
        [void]$Dest.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select()}
     Else{ #If there is data go to the next empty row and select Column A
        [void]$source.ActiveSheet.Range("A2","F$(($Source.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows|Select -Last 1).Row)").Copy()
        [void]$Dest.Activate()
        [void]$Dest.ActiveSheet.Range    ("A$(($Dest.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows|Select -last 1).row+1)").Select()}
    [void]$Dest.ActiveSheet.Paste()
    $Source.Close()}
    $Dest.SaveAs("C:\Users\bob\Desktop\Und\combo\Combined.xlsx",51)
    $Dest.close()
    $Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: You are hard coding the F column. I would also look into selecting all of the active area without using interactive statements which can be slow and error prone.

Comment: You should provide with a minimal and reproducible example. Please refer the [ask] link for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the column typo. What would you change them to instead? I am also trying to have an additional sheet copied as well from the same workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the excellent PoserShell module [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) (with PowerShell 5 or more)

First, install the module:

- in an Administrator PowerShell console: `Install-Module -Name ImportExcel`
- in a non Administrator PowerShell console: `Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -Scope CurrentUser`

Then, use the following code:

```
$source      = 'C:\Users\bob\Desktop\Und'
$destination = 'C:\Users\bob\Desktop\Und\combo\Combined.xlsx'
$fileList    = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter '*.xlsx'
foreach ($file in $fileList) {
    $fileContent = Import-Excel -Path $file.FullName
    $excelParameters = @{
        Path          = $destination 
        WorkSheetname = 'Combined'
    }

    if ((Test-Path -Path $destination) -and (Import-Excel @excelParameters)) {
        $excelParameters.Append = $true
    }

    $fileContent | Export-Excel @excelParameters
}
```

This code assumes that all your Excel source files have the same headers and you want all your data in the same WorkSheet. But can be adapted to support other scenarios.